# How to show all contents when class is set to flex-nowrap in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

Recently, I'm developing using bootstrap for a chatting system. But publishing a job is very difficult for me.
I want to develop the message template using bootstrap. I'm only using a bootstrap grid system.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>NickName</div>
        <div class="row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-auto" style="background-color: beige;">
                <div class="row flex-nowrap">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <div class="text-break">
                            FileName : sddfssfdsdfsfdsdfsfddssdffdssfdsdfsdfsfdsdffdsfsdfsdsfdssfdsdfadsasdadsadsadsdasadsadsdaadsasdasds
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            SIZE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-auto align-self-center">  
                        <img src="./images/ic-download-doc-nor.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto align-self-center text-nowrap">
                PM 7:32
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show all contents when class is set to flex-nowrap. But above code is not working well.
If I reduce browser size in the above code, then the image tag and PM7:32 are hidden.
I don't know what to do. I want to show the following picture always.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with class **col** and **col-auto** inside **row** structure and use **text-break** class for braking single line text without spaces.

I hope this below snippet will help you a lot.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div>NickName</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row flex-nowrap align-items-center rounded py-2" style="background-color: beige;">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="text-break">
                <strong class="float-left mr-1">FileName:</strong> sddfssfdsdfsddsdffdsfsddssfdsdfsdfsfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsdfdsdffdsfsddsdffdsfsddssfdsdfsdfsfdsdffdsfsddffdsfsdfdsdfdffdsfsdfdsdf-Last Text
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong>Size:</strong> 100kb
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <img src="./images/ic-download-doc-nor.png"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto text-nowrap">
          PM 7:32
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to show characters such as dots(.....).   I want to show contents via break-text.

Comment: I don't want to omit it.

Comment: Very thank you, But this code fill area except of  time column. I want to fill only contents size. ex) My origin code used col-auto, col-auto.

Comment: Don't set both column as col-auto. So 1st should be **col** and last one should be **col-auto** then that will not fill area of time column.

Comment: I don't want to fill all of message column, I want to fill only message width. not message column width. But if I use col, then it fill all of column area. How to do this?

Comment: As you want same as attached image? If yes then long text will hide.

Comment: No. I'm fine. Thank  you very much. Additionally, I set max-width of div container, but, I don't know how to set align to right or center. Can you tell me about this?

Answer (score 0):

"d-flex" is important. You can try:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-nowrap">
  ...
</div>
```